# Erro no xaml dizendo que o tipo não foi encontrado

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xaml

No meu xaml eu tenho:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Opa"   
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"  
             x:Class="Opa.MainPage">

    <maps:Map MapType="Street" />
...

</ContentPage>
```

> O tipo 'maps:Map' não foi encontrado. Verifique se não há uma
>   referência de assembly ausente e se todos os assemblies referenciados
>   foram criados.

Mas observem que ele está declarado no header do ContentPage, nessa linha:

`xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"`

Por que o erro?

**Edit1**

Meu projeto se chama Ola

Assim tá meu cabeçalho

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ola"   
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms"  
             x:Class="Ola.MainPage">

    <maps:Map MapType="Street" />
```

Comment: já conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Cara, desde que eu postei não consegui parar. Hoje chego mais cedo em casa e vou dar continuidade. Resolvendo eu fecho o post e marco a resposta.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, ainda não resolvi mas logo logo eu resolvo

Answer (score 1):

Você está invertendo as coisas, `assembly` é o nome da dll e normalmente tem o mesmo nome do seu projeto, se o o que está em questão se chama apenas `Xamarin` o assembly é apenas `Xamarin` e não `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` que seria o caminho com o namespace da classe que representa o controle maps. Mas provavelmente o nome do seu projeto deve ser `Xamarin.Forms`

```
 xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms"
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição em como está meu cabeçalho